# How to split a list into a list of smaller lists by object property?

Tags: kotlin

So I am trying to find the most efficient way to split a list of objects by a property they have into a smaller list then add that list to a new list it sounds confusing but if you read the code I think you will understand

```
class Test {

    @Test
    private fun printEmployeesInShipping(){
        val employeesByDepartment = getEmployeesByDepartment()
        for (department in employeesByDepartment) {
            if(department.get(0).department.equals("Shipping")){
                for (employee in department) println("Name:$employee")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getEmployeesByDepartment(): List<List<Employee>>{
        val listOfEmployee = ArrayList<Employee>()
        listOfEmployee.add(Employee("Bob", "Shipping"))
        listOfEmployee.add(Employee("Stacy", "Shipping"))
        listOfEmployee.add(Employee("Tom", "Sales"))
        listOfEmployee.add(Employee("John", "Sales"))
        listOfEmployee.add(Employee("Jim", "Accounting"))
        listOfEmployee.add(Employee("Kim", "Accounting"))
        //What is the most efficient way to split this list into separate lists and return it

    }

}
data class Employee (
        val name: String? = null,
        val department:String? = null
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
private fun getEmployeesByDepartment(): List<List<Employee>>{
    // [ ... ]
    return listOfEmployee.groupBy { it.department }.map { it.value }
}
```